# Why does this imported .FBX appear differently in Blender?

Tags: armature, import, .fbx

I recently made a character model in Maya.

[image: The character model, as viewed in Autodesk Maya.]

This model looks fine in Unity and Microsoft 3D viewer:

[image: A comparison between how the model looks in Unity and Microsoft 3D viewer]

However, In Blender, it looks... off.

[image: A view of the character model in Blender.]

I'm assuming this has something to do with my import settings in Blender, as it's the only program that isn't displaying the model (and armature) properly. What am I doing wrong?

You can find the .fbx file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uy3z1dGkTIPyizp2WnOddhKrQdValhMG/view?usp=sharing)!

Comment: FBX support is not perfect in Blender. I would recommend trying another format if possible. Collada maybe? Also rigging technologies in different software packages are quite different, it wouldn't be surprising if  you simply cannot use a rig made in Maya inside Blender. It might be better to export geometry only and recreate rigs and materials in the software you need them in.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, there is a good reason for FBX support being not perfect in Blender. In order to support FBX, one needs to use FBX SDK that, If I understand it correctly, is licensed in a way not compatible with GPL license Blender's Python API has. So support for FBX is difficult in Blender because FBX SDK cannot be used with Blender. ...or something like that.  It's good idea to try to use other, more open formats with Blender whenever possible.